# facebook canvas blank on javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, canvas

can anyone can solve this problem because why on this code in my facebook canvas app it loads blank page?.  when i linked to https://awgame.8ternals.com/games with my facebook account logged in it seems works fine. here is the code:

```
 <script>


    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '609246715874390',
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.2'
      });

      // ADD ADDITIONAL FACEBOOK CODE HERE
      FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 640, height: 480 });
     var element = document.getElementById('allContent');
      FB.Canvas.showFlashElement(element);
      function onLogin(response) {
        if (response.status == 'connected') {
          FB.api('/me?fields=first_name', function(data) {
            var welcomeBlock = document.getElementById('fb-welcome');
            welcomeBlock.innerHTML = 'Hello, ' + data.first_name + '!';
          });
        }
      }

      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        // Check login status on load, and if the user is
        // already logged in, go directly to the welcome message.
        if (response.status == 'connected') {
          onLogin(response);
        } else {
          // Otherwise, show Login dialog first.
          FB.login(function(response) {
            onLogin(response);
          }, {scope: 'user_friends, email'});
        }
      });
    };

    (function(d, s, id){
       var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
     }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

 </script>
```

Any Help Will Be grateful to shown my facebook canvas app

Comment: You need HTTPS for a canvas app, since facebook.com is solely served via HTTPS these days. When I request `https://awserver.8ternals.com/` in my browser however, your server asks for a client certificate for authentication. So see to it that you get that fixed.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mentioned before. i already set HTTPS on my app but on https://awserver.8ternals.com/  link opened if you already logged on facebook. is it necessary to submit my apps to facebook team for my canvas is not white page again?

Comment: No, you do not need to submit for review for something to show up on canvas. Again, calling the HTTPS version of your page asks me for a _client certificate_, and that is clearly wrong.

Comment: @CBroe i already resetting the ssl with my ssl provider and ignoring the client certificate. but it still blank when showing the canvas app.

Comment: When I try to visit the address in my browser, it is _still_ asking me for a client certificate …

Comment: @CBroe please see this : http://postimg.org/image/soxypy72t/

Comment: i almost forgot the url changed from https://awserver.8ternals.com to https://awgame.8ternals.com/games i will edit my post too

Comment: OK, https://awgame.8ternals.com/games/ doesn’t ask me for a certificate, but only shows me a page with a green background and nothing more on it.

Comment: @CBroe yes but still in the link https://apps.facebook.com/awindonesia is blank iframe

Comment: Your app simply delivers an _empty_ document when requested via POST (and that is how apps are loaded into the canvas iframe, via a POST request.)

Comment: so all i need to do is catch the POST params?

Comment: Well, you need to make your app’s start URL output _something_ when a POST request is made to it.

Comment: can you provide me the example about that? links are okay with me

Comment: Don’t know much about asp … but how to make your app accept POST requests and output a response you should be able to find out yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so the problem is solved. first, i change file from html to aspx. second, on my app dashboard i change link https://awgame.8ternals.com/games/ to https://awgame.8ternals.com/games/tes.aspx?